# SVG text element not positioning correctly

Tags: svg

I've set up a minimalist example of what I have [here](https://jsfiddle.net/va77ahzk/). I need to position the text element at the very top of the SVG. However if you inspect the text element, you'll see that it actually starts somewhere outside the SVG (like -3px on Chrome, -4px on FF) -- see below screenshot. I'm building something which needs to be pixel-perfect, so I need to get the text to start exactly where the SVG starts. As you can see, the `rect` starts where it's supposed to.

Since SO won't let me post links to jsfiddle without code inside the post, here's the code:

```
<svg width="100%" height="360" style="background-color: rgb(0, 249, 253);margin-top: 50px;">
  <rect y1="0" y2="100" x="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  <text x="100" y="0" dominant-baseline="hanging">2022</text>
</svg>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: The space is to allow for accents. There's no way to account for that other than trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties), a dominant baseline of `hanging` is only meaningful for Indic scripts like Devanagari. If you want the top edge of the text box to align with a particular Y coordinate, then use `text-before-edge` instead:

```html
<svg width="300" height="55" viewBox="0 0 300 55">
  <rect x="20" y="5" width="30" height="30" fill="#f00"/>
  <text x="50" y="5" dominant-baseline="hanging">8888</text>
  <text x="35" y="50" text-anchor="middle">hanging</text>
  <rect x="220" y="5" width="30" height="30" fill="#f00"/>
  <text x="250" y="5" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">8888</text>
  <text x="235" y="50" text-anchor="middle">text-before-edge</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, even if I remove the `dominant-baseline` altogether, it's still  aligning weirdly (except it aligns at the bottom part). Well, since your solution is working, I'm not gonna question it any further. Thanks.