SVG text is incorrectly overlapping
I'm trying to upload my SVG to a QLabel:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    DisplaySvgOnLabel();
}

void MainWindow::DisplaySvgOnLabel() {
    QSvgRenderer svg_renderer;

    bool isLoaded = svg_renderer.load(QString(R"(C:/.../map.svg)"));

    if (!isLoaded) {
        qDebug() << "Не удалось загрузить SVG файл.";
        return;
    }

    QSize label_size = ui->label->size();

    QPixmap pixmap(label_size);
    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    svg_renderer.render(&painter, QRectF(10, 10, label_size.width() - 30, label_size.height() - 30));

    ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
}

Example SVG:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polyline points="886.635,702 921.308,389.01 780.048,466.526 886.635,702" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="14" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <polyline points="921.308,389.01 780.048,466.526 40,40 780.048,466.526 921.308,389.01" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255,160,0)" stroke-width="14" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="886.635" y="702" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">297</text>
  <text fill="green" x="886.635" y="702" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">297</text>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="921.308" y="389.01" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">635</text>
  <text fill="rgb(255,160,0)" x="921.308" y="389.01" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">635</text>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="40" y="40" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">635</text>
  <text fill="rgb(255,160,0)" x="40" y="40" dx="7" dy="17" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana" font-weight="bold">635</text>
  <circle cx="921.308" cy="389.01" r="5" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="886.635" cy="702" r="5" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="5" fill="white"/>
  <circle cx="780.048" cy="466.526" r="5" fill="white"/>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="921.308" y="389.01" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Biryulyovo Tovarnaya</text>
  <text fill="black" x="921.308" y="389.01" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Biryulyovo Tovarnaya</text>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="886.635" y="702" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Biryulyovo Zapadnoye</text>
  <text fill="black" x="886.635" y="702" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Biryulyovo Zapadnoye</text>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="40" y="40" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Prazhskaya</text>
  <text fill="black" x="40" y="40" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Prazhskaya</text>
  <text fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.85)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="780.048" y="466.526" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Universam</text>
  <text fill="black" x="780.048" y="466.526" dx="7" dy="-3" font-size="20" font-family="Verdana">Universam</text>
</svg>

But after successful upload, my number is overlapped by the text:

But if I open the drawing in the browser, the text is displayed as needed, no overlapping:

Why is this happening?
I'm using Qt 6.6.3 on Windows 11.

different end of line?

text fits over the number

I think we would need an example SVG here, how else would we test the issue and try solutions? If my guess is correct, you first make these map SVGs, so try to make a very simple one (as single dot?), and [edit] your question to include it as text, formatted as code. Oh, and share the Qt version and OS you're currently using, just in case.

Maybe it can't handle dx and dy. Try give the text the desired x and y values without using the dx and dy.

Here's a [mre]: https://hastebin.com/share/rixunumika.cpp

The problem is not Qt specific, if you try to view that SVG in multiple viewers, especially non-web ones, you will see the same problem. The problem is indeed the dx/dy and how it gets handled. From a quick search, you could either use tspan, g transoform="translate(x, y)", QWebEngineView (too much). The options are limited.

there are also some Qt-specific things with svg implemetation related to that some defalt values not assumed equal to standard defaults (e.g. default style). SOme featues of text positioning of svg are even locale dependant, not only implementation dependant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800767/svg-text-element-not-positioning-correctly

Qt only fully supports SVG 1.2 Tiny, for which the text element does not support dx or dy. Since 6.7 the support has been partially extended to some features of SVG 1.1 (but the docs don't mention adding those attributes for text, I cannot test it right now). You should be very careful when working with text alignments, though, as they always depend on the installed fonts.

@musicamante According to what I've read in Qt6 support is well beyond Tiny 1.2  but still not full SVG2. But even some "full" SVG implementations do not respect dx/dy and use some coordinate-snapping technique similar to Tiny.

Quite a few svg renderers align text vertically, because default alignment is automatic, dx/dy not respected. In case of Qt's SVG Tiny only few features are supported https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12/text.html#TextLayout
Possible solution is to use dominant-baseline different from auto or define text's bounding rectangle


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50" y="50" dominant-baseline="text-after-edge">297</text>
    <text x="50" y="50" dominant-baseline="text-before-edge">TEXT</text>
</svg>



